# Gaining access to events in tkinter between objects

Tags: python, events, tkinter, callback

In this sample python/tkinter script I have 3 classes. My first class SandBox sets up a notebook with two tabs, each tab is a separate class object.

This script is not a real world script I'm working on, it's just an attempt to add something simple here to help explain my question.

I'm trying to determine how to have the PageTwo object notified of changes from the PageOne object. For example, when data is added to the list box in PageOne I'd like PageTwo to be notified of the change and have access to the data that was added. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class PageOne:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def init_ui(self, page):
        self.lb_test_one = Listbox(page, selectmode=SINGLE)
        self.lb_test_one.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10, sticky=W + E)
        self.lb_test_one.configure(exportselection=False)
        self.lb_test_one.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.on_test_one_selected)

        # UI Row 3
        self.b_add_data = Button(page, text="Add Data", command=self.on_add_data)
        self.b_add_data.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=10, sticky=N + S + E + W)
        return page

    counter = 0
    def on_add_data(self):
        self.lb_test_one.insert(self.counter, 'Test Data: {}'.format(self.counter))
        self.counter += 1

    def on_test_one_selected(self, evt):
        event_data = evt.widget
        if len(event_data.curselection()) > 0:
            index = int(event_data.curselection()[0])
            value = event_data.get(index)


class PageTwo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def init_ui(self, page):
        self.lb_test_two = Listbox(page, selectmode=SINGLE)
        self.lb_test_two.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10, sticky=W + E)
        self.lb_test_two.configure(exportselection=False)

        return page


class SandBox:
    root_tk = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.root_tk = Tk()
        self.root_tk.geometry("250x350")
        nb = ttk.Notebook(self.root_tk)
        nb.add(PageOne().init_ui(ttk.Frame(nb)), text='Tab One')
        nb.add(PageTwo().init_ui(ttk.Frame(nb)), text='Tab Two')
        nb.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
        self.root_tk.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SandBox()
```

Comment: Your indentation is broken. Is `init_ui`, `counter`, `on_add_data` and `on_test_one_selected` all part of `PageOne`?

Comment: Why are you using `pass` in `__init__` and then creating everything you would normally create using `__init__` in a separate init method?

Comment: Also please add some context to you question. What exactly are you notifying the 2nd page about and what are you expecting the 2nd page to do with this information?

Comment: This is too broad. There are many ways to accomplish what you want, from having PageOne directly call a method in PageTwo, to setting up a generic publish/subscribe solution.

Comment: @BryanOakley - Yes Just looking for a general purpose solution on how to send data between multiple pages based off events. The above script was just an attempt to help explain what I need, like adding data to a list box in the first page, and being notified of that in the 2nd page, the specifics of what I would do with the data is not the question, but if it helps one thing that might be done is add the data to the list box in page 2 that's added to page 1.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks Bryan. I'll do some more research, the question is broad at this point due to my lack of experience/knowledge in this area so I'm not sure how to be more specific. I'll do some additional digging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to set up `SandBox` as a controller with which you can implement a publish/subscribe system. Each page can call the `notify` method of the controller, which can then call the `notify` method of all of the subscribers.

It starts by giving each page a reference to the controller:

```
class Sandbox:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        page1 = PageOne(controller=self)
        page2 = PageTwo(controller=self)
```

Then, each page can call a method on the controller to send information:

```
class PageOne:
    def __init__(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        ...
    def on_add_data(self):
        ...
        self.controller.notify("some data")
```

`SandBox` can either iterate over all known pages (by saving references to each page in a list) or it can provide a method so that other pages can ask to be added to the list (ie: a `subscribe` method)

For an example of the former, it's as simple as

```
class SandBox:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        page1 = PageOne(controller=self)
        page2 = PageTwo(controller=self)
        self.subscribers=[page1, page2]
        ...
    def notify(self, data):
        for page in self.subscribers:
            page.notify(data)
```

You then need to implement `notify` for each page to do whatever it is you want it to do when it receives the data.

That's just the basic concept. Must pub/sub systems allow you to subscribe to certain types of events, so that all data isn't sent to every subscriber all the time. For example. PageOne probably doesn't care about when PageOne changes.

You can implement this by introducing a `subscribe` method in the controller where you pass in the type of information you are subscribing to, and a function to call for that type of message. In this context, "type" is very much like an event in Tkinter. It can be implemented as a simple string, it doesn't have to be anything fancy.

In PageTwo:

```
def __init__(...):
    ...
    # tell the controller that when a notification with a type of
    # "list_changed" is received it should call self.on_list_changed
    self.controller.subscribe("list_changed", self.on_list_changed)
    ...

def on_list_changed(self, data):
    print("data received:", data)
```

In PageOne:

```
# send a "list_changed" message with some data
self.controller.notify("list_changed", "some data...")
```

In SandBox:

```
self.subscribers = {}
...
def subscribe(self, message_type, callback):
    self.subscriptions.setdefault(message_type, [])
    self.subscriptions[message_type].append(callback)

def notify(self, message_type, data):
    for callback in self.subscriptions[message_type]:
        # call the callback, sending it the data
        callback(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with multiple classes you can either pass the frame or the object to the class that should be interacting with the other.

You can even use variable names to work with the class attributes from outside of the class

Here is an example code that shows how you can interact with data from one class to another and from an outside class to the instance of the main class.

```
import tkinter as tk


class LeftFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.l_text = tk.Text(self.parent, width = 40, height = 10)
        self.l_text.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.l_text.bind("<Key>", self.return_data)

    def return_data(self, event):
        data = self.l_text.get(1.0, tk.END)
        # uses the variable name "app" assigned to the main window class.
        # then calls a method inside that class to append the data from another class text box
        app.add_to_right_frame(data) 


class RightFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.r_text = tk.Text(self.parent, width = 40, height = 10)
        self.r_text.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.r_text.bind("<Key>", self.return_data)

    def return_data(self, event):
        data = self.r_text.get(1.0, tk.END)
        # uses the variable name "app" assigned to the main window class.
        # then calls a method inside that class to append the data from another class text box
        app.add_to_left_frame(data)


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.master = root
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        #makes a class attribute of each frame so it can be manipulated later            
        self.f1 = LeftFrame(self.main_frame)
        self.f2 = RightFrame(self.main_frame)

    def add_to_left_frame(self, data):
        self.f1.l_text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        self.f1.l_text.insert(1.0, data)

    def add_to_right_frame(self, data):
        self.f2.r_text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        self.f2.r_text.insert(1.0, data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The result is a window with 2 text boxes created from external classes and the ability to type in one box and have it show up in the other and visa versa.